# Does boot take up any significant power?

Tags: battery-life, boot

If I wanted to conserve energy, and needed to check on my phone once every while, would turning the phone off and on every 30 seconds actually conserve more power than if I had it on all the time?

Does the boot sequence perhaps take more energy than the energy I saved in the off time, thus having negative "profit" of power save?

---

My phone is running CyanogenMod 12.1, and is a kminilte (S5 mini)

Comment: Are you asking about booting, meaning from a powered off state, or waking the device (tapping power to turn on the screen)? Booting every 30 sec is not practical since the boot process takes longer than that, if you meant every 30 minutes, then you are better off leaving it on.

Comment: @acejavelin Waking the device is **not** booting, as no init, and kernel start takes place. I agree it is impractical, but if it saved energy (which is doubtful after answer from GiantTree), I would do it

Comment: Giant tree's answer is correct... Booting the device takes a significant amount of power by comparison... Depending on the device, a properly sleeping device could probably run up to an hour on the power it takes for the 1-2 minute boot process and the necessary syncs and checks afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, booting the device is very expensive in terms of power consumption.

Many reads from the storage and lots of computation needs to be done when booting the device so that you need considerable off time to justify turning it off.

Android's power conservation features (deep sleep, dozing etc) allow you to keep your phone turned on all the time and still consume less energy than booting it freshly.